# Finding the number of syllables in a string of text

Tags: string-manipulation, linguistics

To implement a readability algorithm, I need to find the number of symbols in a long string of text (almost 5000 words). There doesn't seem to be a built-in *Mathematica* function that can count the number of syllables in an English word or string of words. What is the fastest and most efficient way to find this value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should look at [`WordData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordData.html).

```
WordData["hyphenation", "Hyphenation"]
```

> `{"hy", "phen", "a", "tion"}`

The definition of what is a syllable in English is tricky. The algorithm used by `WordData` may give results that do not agree with the syllable division you will find in a particular dictionary (which may give more than one syllable division for a given word), but I think mapping `WordData` over the words in your text would be the easiest way to proceed in Mathematica.

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented my function as such:
`wordSyllableCount[word_] := WordData[word, "Hyphenation"] // Length`

Answer (score 6):

The Unified Syllable Theory for *English* is due shortly after the unification of the relativity and quantum theories and the cure for the common cold.  Can I talk you into using a language with a simpler syllable definition?  *Esperanto*, maybe?  No?

Kidding aside, we could try using the built-in hyphenation functionality as a way to approximate syllable count:

```
WordData["antidisestablishmentarianism", "Hyphenation"]
(* {"an", "ti", "dis", "es", "tab", "lish", "men", "tar", "i", "an", "ism"} *)

% // Length
(* 11 *)
```

To try this out, let's take the first 20 unique words from *Alice In Wonderland*...

```
$words =
  ExampleData[{"Text","AliceInWonderland"}] //
  ToLowerCase // 
  StringCases[#, LetterCharacter..]& //
  Union //
  Take[#, 20]&;
```

... and review the hyphenation data:

```
{#, WordData[#, "Hyphenation"]}& /@ $words // Grid
```

[image: syllable grid]

Hmmm... a lot of missing data.  Oh, right... *English*.  We can replace the missing data with an approximation based upon letter count:

```
fixup[{w_, s_List}] := {w, Length[s]}
fixup[{w_, _Missing}] := {w, Ceiling[StringLength[w] / 3]}
```

So then...

```
fixup @ {#, WordData[#, "Hyphenation"]}& /@ $words // Grid
```

[image: fixed up syllable grid]

This seems workable.  Adjust `fixup` to taste.

Comment: Just the first paragraph warranted a +1. :D